# Cant ping neither the gateway nor the internet if not already pinged with the gateway

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, iptables

Im quite new to networking, i tried to look for the response to my problem but i didnt find it.

I have 4 vm's, that we will call 1,2,3,4. The first ( the gateway) one have a host-only and bridge network card, the others only have a host-only.

I settled some iptables rules to redirect the vm's 2,3,4 packets to the gateway to give them acces to the internet, it worked, but i cant neither ping the gateway nor 8.8.8.8 e.g. as long as i didnt pinged the vm's with the first one (the gateway), after i did this i can ping the gw, google and all that, before that ic an only ping the local machines. I would like to have access to the internet and to ping the GW without having to ping it with the GW.

Here are the iptables rules that i settled :

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
```

There is the interface of the first VM:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo enp0s8
iface lo inet loopback
auto lo enp0s3
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and there is one of my others vm's the others have the same, just the ip is different:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
        address 192.168.1.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Thanks !, and is it normal that when i type iptables -S i cant see the last rule above ?

Comment: The last rule is in the `-t nat` table. But what _other_ rules do you have in `FORWARD`?

Comment: Other than the two FORWARD rules that i said above i only have -P FORWARD ACCEPT